# Displaying success popup message after data insertion in codeigniter php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Need to show success message in pop up after data is submitting but the problem is once i click on submit button it is displaying the alert message and later it is submitting the data.

```
<form name="applynow"  id="applynow" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"  action="<?php echo base_url();?>apply/applynow">

            <div class ="applyus">                  
                    <div class="applyfullname contactname">                         
                        <input type="text" class="form-control names namesss" name="fullname"  value="<?php echo set_value('fullname');?>" placeholder="Full Name" required><span class="required">*</span> 
                        <?php echo form_error('fullname', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
                    </div>  

                    <div class="applynowemail contactemail">
                           <input type="email" class="form-control emails" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email');?>" placeholder="Email" required >  <span class="requireds">*</span>                           
                        <?php echo form_error('email', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>                         
                    </div>  

<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success successss" id="submits" >Submit</button>
```

Script:

```
<script>
$('form').on('submit',function(){
       alert('submitted');
});
```

Once the data is submitted it should display the popup and the page should redirect to another page.

Tried with Ajax:

```
<span class="success">Thank's for submitting the form</span>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("form[name='applynow']").submit(function() {
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "career.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function() {
            $('.sucess').fadeIn(100).show();

        }
    })

})
})
```

Apply Now Controller:

```
public function applynow($job_id)
{
    if ($this->input->post('email')) 
    {          
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error"> ', '</span>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fullname', 'First Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'required');            

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
        {
            $data['records2']= $this->career_model->getcareerdatas($job_id);
            $data['mainpage']='apply';
            $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);               
        } 
        else 
        {                
            $inputCaptcha = $this->input->post('captcha');
            $sessCaptcha  = $this->session->userdata('captchaCode');               
            if ($inputCaptcha === $sessCaptcha) 
            {
                $result = $this->apply_model->apply($this->input->post('email'));
                $data['records2']= $this->career_model->getcareerdatas($job_id);
                return true;
                if ($result) 
                {
                    $this->flash->success('<h2 style="color:green">Thank You applying to this post!will get back you soon once shortlisted..</h2>');
                    redirect('apply');
                } else 
                {
                    $this->flash->success('<h2 style="color:red">Sorry ! Message sending failed</h2>');
                    redirect('apply');
                }
            } else {
                $this->flash->success('<h2 style="color:red">Captcha code was not match, please try again.</h2>');
                redirect('apply');
            }                
        }
    }
    $config  = array(
        'img_path' => 'captcha_images/',
        'img_url' => base_url() . 'captcha_images/',
        'img_width' => '150',
        'img_height' => 40,
        'word_length' => 6,
        'font_size' => 30
    );
    $captcha = create_captcha($config);
    $word    = $captcha['word'];
    $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaCode');
    $this->session->set_userdata('captchaCode', $word);
    $data['captchaImg'] = $captcha['image'];
    $data['mainpage']   = "apply";
}
```

Comment: If you want to show success message after submitting data then you have to use ```$this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'success');```. It will display on next page which you want to show on success.

Comment: @kishor10d that is working fine i have done that but need to display message in popup

Comment: Then use ajax to submit the form values, on ```success``` you have to show the message.

Comment: @kishor10d updated my code with Ajax code which i have tried it is not working

Comment: ```$("form[name='applynow']").submit(function()``` this thing is submitting your form to server side. This is not ajax. This is normal submit but by using jquery. You better use ```$("#button").click(function() { // your ajax });```

Comment: @kishor10d can you change in my question

Comment: Please check, I done with the change.

Comment: @kishor10d where you have edited the answer

Comment: are you using bootstrap? @user8001297

Comment: No i am using bootstrap for popup

Comment: @user8001297 : I edited your question for the answer. Please check, I think you get edit request in notification.

Comment: @kishor10d last edited 1 hour ago which was edited by me only

Comment: @user8001297 : please try the answer of Lekus Alexey, it will work for you. I done the same thing.

Comment: @kishor10d i have tried that it is showing an alert box sned data to apply/applynow  thats it if  i close the poup then not displaying anything the data is not inserting

Comment: @user8001297 : It is not the complete code which you want, you have to write something on server-side (in codeigniter) for that. You have write, controller to receive the variables from ajax, and then model to insert the values in database. etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class ="applyus">                  
<div class="applyfullname contactname">                         
<input type="text" class="form-control names namesss" name="fullname"  value="" placeholder="Full Name" >
</div>  

<div class="applynowemail contactemail">
   <input type="email" class="form-control emails" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email"  >                                                 
</div>  
<button class="btn btn-success successss" id="sub" >Submit</button> 
<script>
$("#sub").click(function() {
    var url = 'applynow.php';

    var data = {
        'namesss' : $(".namesss").val(),
        'emails' : $(".emails").val()
    }

    alert('Data before send is:');
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data
    }).done(function(str) {
    alert('Data from php is:');
        alert(JSON.stringify(str));
        var result = JSON.parse(str);
        alert(result['variable1']);
        alert(result['variable2']);
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

applynow.php :

```
<?php
class test() {
    public function applynow($job_id)
    {
        $result = [];
        $result['variable1'] = 'name is: ' . $_POST['namesss'];
        $result['variable2'] = 'email is: ' . $_POST['emails'];
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}

$test = new test();
$test->applynow('1');
```

And you see alert "aaa"; all works

---

in your real code you need replace 
$this->flash->success('test'); to echo 'test';
and delete redirect('apply'); from php

in this js you need change path to php script

Comment: url: url, in the place of url what to be replaced

Comment: If you change JQUERY Selector to right I think this solution is working

Comment: Tried with that code it is redirecting to career page not displaying popup

Comment: you need delete <form> tag

Comment: displaying the pop up as send date to apply/applynow after that it is not working if i close the alert box

Comment: Clicking on submit button not displaying anything submit is not working

Comment: You can copy this code to html file and run it. It work perfectly.

Comment: This is only example only , you need change in this example   url and in php you can add at least one echo, after php finish work - you get alert -  alert(JSON.stringify(str));

Comment: I have tried this but it is not submitting the data if we remove the form action from the code and it is displaying the pop with all the css links which we will be writing in header file

Comment: you can write in your php <?php write('1.txt', print_r($_POST, true); ?>  and see all variables that you send to php script.  You need delete all included css and other things. Alert show you all data that php returned. You need change your php until you don't get only result data. After it you can change alert to something like this  "var result = JSON.parse(str);"

Comment: You can run only my example and see that all works fine

Comment: Can you provide any fiddle link where it is working i mean to say your working code example

Comment: applynow is a function which i called in controller

Comment: Once submitted it is not displaying any pop up as success message successfully sent like that

Comment: Fiddle working only with JS code  , but here we have js and php code.  Change your "applynow" to my sample "applynow".  Or copy my 2 files to your server and run it.

Comment: Actually i am using codeigniter framework no need to display any data in popup i only need to show success message after submit thats it

Comment: AS of success message is not coming it is displaying data which we have entered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151261/discussion-between-user8001297-and-lesuk-alexey).

Answer (score 0):

Please make some changes in your code like give below.

```
<form name="applynow"  id="applynow" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

            <div class ="applyus">                  
                    <div class="applyfullname contactname">                         
                        <input type="text" class="form-control names namesss" name="fullname"  value="<?php echo set_value('fullname');?>" placeholder="Full Name" required><span class="required">*</span> 
                        <?php echo form_error('fullname', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
                    </div>  

                    <div class="applynowemail contactemail">
                           <input type="email" class="form-control emails" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email');?>" placeholder="Email" required >  <span class="requireds">*</span>                           
                        <?php echo form_error('email', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>                         
                    </div>  

<button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success successss" id="submits" >Submit</button>
```

You must use `async: false` that will instruct to the browser first complete this request,  then go for other codes

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#applynow').validate({

            rules: { 



            },

            messages: {

            },


            submitHandler: function (form) {
var url ="<?php echo base_url();?>apply/applynow";  
var reDirectUrl = "<?php echo base_url();?>career.php"; 

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        async : false,
        success: function(data){ 
         // console.log('data', data);
             if(data == 1){
              $('.sucess').fadeIn(100).show(); // Need to set the success msg in the popup " Thank You applying to this post!will get back you soon once shortlisted.. "

             }else if(data == 0){
              // Do Something like this>> $('.failed').fadeIn(100).show(); // Sorry ! Message sending failed
             }


        }
    })

})
});
 </script>
```

Changes in apply now controller:

```
 public function applynow($job_id)
{
    if ($this->input->post('email')) 
    {          
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error"> ', '</span>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fullname', 'First Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'required');            

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
        {
            $data['records2']= $this->career_model->getcareerdatas($job_id);
            $data['mainpage']='apply';
            $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);               
        } 
        else 
        {                
            $inputCaptcha = $this->input->post('captcha');
            $sessCaptcha  = $this->session->userdata('captchaCode');               
            if ($inputCaptcha === $sessCaptcha) 
            {
                $result = $this->apply_model->apply($this->input->post('email'));
                $data['records2']= $this->career_model->getcareerdatas($job_id);
                return true;
                if ($result) 
                {
                   echo '1'; exit;
//                    $this->flash->success('<h2 style="color:green">Thank You applying to this post!will get back you soon once shortlisted..</h2>');
//                    redirect('apply');
                } else 
                {
                   echo '0'; exit;
//                    $this->flash->success('<h2 style="color:red">Sorry ! Message sending failed</h2>');
//                    redirect('apply');
                }
            } else {                 

                $this->flash->success('<h2 style="color:red">Captcha code was not match, please try again.</h2>');
                redirect('apply');
            }                
        }
    }
    $config  = array(
        'img_path' => 'captcha_images/',
        'img_url' => base_url() . 'captcha_images/',
        'img_width' => '150',
        'img_height' => 40,
        'word_length' => 6,
        'font_size' => 30
    );
    $captcha = create_captcha($config);
    $word    = $captcha['word'];
    $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaCode');
    $this->session->set_userdata('captchaCode', $word);
    $data['captchaImg'] = $captcha['image'];
    $data['mainpage']   = "apply";
}
```

I hope this may helps you. Thanks!

Comment: carrer.php is the page where it redirects after submit

Comment: Changed the code with the one which you have posted but it is not working it is redirecting to career page

Comment: Changed the code but it is not displaying any popup success message

Comment: can u pls show me ur 'applynow()' in the 'apply' controller?

Comment: Updated in my question

Comment: success: function(data){ 
         // console.log('data', data);
             if(data == 1){
              $('.sucess').fadeIn(100).show(); // Need to set the success msg in the popup " Thank You applying to this post!will get back you soon once shortlisted.. "

             }else if(data == 0){
              // Do Something like this>> $('.failed').fadeIn(100).show(); // Sorry ! Message sending failed
             }

Comment: not getting this lines which you have mentioned in comment section

Comment: It is nothing but, if u applied the post successfully u will get the return value as '1' , that is in the success function 'data' will be '1'.

Comment: I have your code in my code but popup is not coming

Comment: @AbdulSalam : You answer is good but don't you think that ```$("#applynow").submit(function()``` this line will produce normal form submit (not ajax).

Comment: Data is inserting successfully but popup is not displaying

Comment: pls console the return data like console.log('data', data);

Comment: pls check the value of data on the browser console

Comment: @user8001297 Pls change the script as given

Comment: Changed the script as given by you but the popup is not displaying

Comment: did u get console data?

Comment: Pls uncomment and verify the value of data by console.log('data', data);

Comment: @user8001297 : from here, we can not give you complete code. We can suggest the ways to achieve. But other things you need to do. You didn't get alert because you didn't get anything from server side. May be you got errors, so the alert not showing. You need to sort out that programming errors.

Comment: @kishor10d it is working fine because i am getting email but unable to get the popup

Comment: @user8001297 : it is alert, not popup. ok. have you echo'ed something from controller?

Comment: @AbdulSalam uncommented console.log('data', data);  but not getting any data in console

Comment: U know the limitation of communication through Stack Overflow, so i can't tell u any thing more without referring ur complete code, Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look at this
http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/